# Angular 2 submit JSON within JSON

Tags: angularjs, json, angular, typescript

I am trying to use an import function where a user can import raw JSON and then it posts to the server.

for example if a user pastes this json:

```
{
  "name": "testing",
  "design": [
    {
      "name": "test",
      "comments": [
        {
          "short": "123",
          "long": "1234567890"
        }
      ],
      "maxMark": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Then i want all of that to get sent the server.
Not sure the best of way handling such a task though.

Right now i have a simple form:

```
<modal #importModal [keyboard]="false" [backdrop]="'static'">
                        <modal-header [show-close]="false">
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Importing a module</h4>
                        </modal-header>
                        <modal-body>
                            <form name="importForm" [ngFormModel]="importForm" (ngSubmit)="importForm.valid" novalidate>
                                <textarea class="form-control" rows="20" #data='ngForm' [ngFormControl]="importForm.controls['data']"></textarea>
                            </form>
                            <pre>{{importForm.value | json }}</pre>
                        </modal-body>
                        <modal-footer>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="importModal.dismiss()"><i class="fa fa-close"></i> Close</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" [disabled]="!importForm.valid" (click)="importModal.dismiss() && submitImport(importForm.value)"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i> Submit</button>
                        </modal-footer>
                    </modal>
```

But the value of the form is showing as:

```
  "data": "{\n  \"name\": \"testing\",\n  \"design\": [\n    {\n      \"name\": \"test\",\n      \"comments\": [\n        {\n          \"short\": \"123\",\n          \"long\": \"1234567890\"\n        }\n      ],\n      \"maxMark\": 0\n    }\n  ]\n}"
```

Do i have to stringify it then strip it or ? What's the best of converting that back into JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just parse it once more:

```js
var form = { "data": "{\n  \"name\": \"testing\",\n  \"design\": [\n    {\n      \"name\": \"test\",\n      \"comments\": [\n        {\n          \"short\": \"123\",\n          \"long\": \"1234567890\"\n        }\n      ],\n      \"maxMark\": 0\n    }\n  ]\n}" };

var dataObject = JSON.parse(form.data);
```

Comment: Ahh brilliiant, I didn't realise you had to parse the form.data makes complete sense now, thanks alot!